# Is it possible to set a transmit power limit to Bluetooth on (some?) Android devices? Or at least monitor it?

Tags: wi-fi, audio, bluetooth

My smartphone is not compatible with Bluetooth LE 5.2 audio, but I still want to limit the power transmitted to earbuds. I know the transmit power is set automatically, but in case it is conservative, is it possible to limit it in software? I do not necessarily need LE audio levels, but at most 10mW guaranteed would be appreciated.

If it's not possible, is it then at least possible to see what the transmit power is in real time?

P.S. I think audio devices do not transmit except for acknowledgement aside from upon boot and pairing. I'll check this next though